# GAN model accuracy decreases after some iterations

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, nvidia

I've been training GAN on Nvidia 4x RTX 3090. It's converging till some point but afterward starts decreasing the image quality and ended-up producing only noisy and distorted images. It can be an excessive heat-up issue of GPU also. **Anyone knows why this happened and the solution?** The code seems to be ok.

Answer (score 2):

This phenomenon that you are experiencing is rather related to Mode Collapse, which is characteristic to GANs. It might also be a VG (vanishing gradient problem).

If you do see that the quality of your model decreases after a specific point, you should maybe cut-off at that specific point or try to use specific GANs related techniques in order to mitigate the problems/help the convergence (see specific types of losses such as Wasserstein loss)

In order to verify your assumption, you would need to carry out numerous tests in which, provided that the temperature rises above some thresholds, some odd phenomenons take place, but I am 99.99% sure that the heat is not at fault, rather:

1. Mode Collapse
2. Vanishing gradient
3. A combination of these two.

Please inspect the link below in order to check these problems:
https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/gan/problems